# Custom argument resolver not being invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller which has the following method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cases/{caseId}", params = "meta", method = PUT, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String updateUIMetadata(@PathVariable("caseId") final String caseId,
       @RequestBody  @JsonData(schemaLocation = "schema/metadata_schema.json") final String metadataJson) {

}
```

I am implementing a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

```
public class ValidateJsonSchema implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {


@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(JsonData.class);
}

@Override
public String resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Inside ValidateJsonSchema");
    String json = (String) getRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor().resolveArgument(parameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);
    return validateJson(json, parameter);

}
}
```

I have registered it as a bean and also an argument resolver in my config file

```
@Bean
public ValidateJsonSchema validateJsonSchema() {
    return new ValidateJsonSchema();
}

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(validateJsonSchema());
}
```

But for some strange reason, the argument resolver class in never called. Is there something I missed?

Edit: JsonData.java

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface JsonData {
public String schemaLocation();
}
```

Edit 2: AppInitializer.java

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET, new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping(MAPPING_URL);
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION);
    return context;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason your custom argument resolver wasn't invoked is that you parameter was already handled by Spring's `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`. That class is in charge of handling of arguments annotated with `@RequestBody`.

To put your argument resolver into play, just remove the `@RequestBody` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your config class is annotated with **`@Configuration`** and also that it extends  **`WebMvcConfigurationSupport`**.

Also use **`@EnableWebMvc`** in your config class.

Comment: Yes it does both of that. Is there anything else I missed?

Comment: I have set a breakpoint at `supportsParameter`. That method is never called. I have included my `JsonData` class too in my edited question. I had included that before.

Comment: My only guess is that you configuration class is being ignored. Is `addArgumentResolvers' being executed? How are you bootstraping your configuration?

Comment: I have included my app initializer class too. I guess it is being called because I have registered all my beans in the same class which are being created.

Comment: Does your config class have the @EnableWebMvc annotation?

Comment: Yes, it does that too.

Comment: Does it prints the system.out line if you remove the @RequestBody annotation?

Comment: That's what I tried initially, because I thought it might not invoke argument resolver because all arguments are already resolved. But no. It does not invoke it even after I remove `@RequestBody`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87762/discussion-between-rockydgeekgod-and-alfonso-presa).

Comment: I have replied in chat

Comment: Updated to reflect that config class needs to extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a RequestBodyAdvice and validate the json in the method beforeBodyRead. The only disadvantage is you will get response 500 when the validation fails, because the controller will never receive the object.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class JsonSchemaBodyAdvice : RequestBodyAdvice {

  @Autowired
  private var jsonValidatorService: JsonValidatorService? = null

  override fun supports(parameter: MethodParameter, type: Type, clazz: Class<out HttpMessageConverter<*>>): Boolean {
    return parameter.parameter.getAnnotation(RequestBody::class.java) != null
  }

  override fun beforeBodyRead(
    message: HttpInputMessage,
    parameter: MethodParameter,
    type: Type,
    clazz: Class<out HttpMessageConverter<*>>
  ): HttpInputMessage {
    val json = String(message.body.readAllBytes())
    
    // VALIDATE SCHEMA HERE

    // we can not reset the original input stream, wrap the json in a new object
    return object : HttpInputMessage {
      override fun getHeaders() = message.headers
      override fun getBody() = ByteArrayInputStream(json.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
    }
  }

  override fun afterBodyRead(
    body: Any,
    message: HttpInputMessage,
    parameter: MethodParameter,
    type: Type,
    clazz: Class<out HttpMessageConverter<*>>
  ): Any {
    return body
  }

  override fun handleEmptyBody(
    body: Any?,
    message: HttpInputMessage,
    parameter: MethodParameter,
    type: Type,
    clazz: Class<out HttpMessageConverter<*>>
  ) = body
}
```

Also you can create your own annotation to set the schema file to the parameter, for instance @ValidRequestBody("schema.json")